# PHP - IMAP test if an email alias exists

Tags: php, imap, postfix-mta, aliases

Is there a programmatic way to test the existence of an email alias when logged in as an IMAP client from a remote host rather than sending an email or having to parse the aliases file on the mail server?

It is a Postfix mail server.

Edit: I found an example of [email validation over SMTP](http://code.google.com/p/php-smtp-email-validation/) and this looks like what I need.   However on my server SMTP does not allow relays and I get a 554 for valid addresses.  I'm wondering if there is an example like this one but for an SMTP server that requires authentication?

Comment: I'm not aware of a prefab library, but basic auth is quite simple with a socket connection: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SMTP_Authentication

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check whether a server accepts mail for an email address with a `fsockopen` on the right MX, and check wether a `RCPT TO` is accepted, but there are some false positives (proxies which blindly accept anything for a domain and pipe it to others servers in the park), and false negatives (grey listing and the like). If there is some sort of command the IMAP protocol (which I doubt) I'm not aware of it.

Comment: Connecting by socket was the trick, send EHLO $domain, and MAIL FROM: address then capture the output after sending a RCPT TO: and validate if a "250" was received.

Comment: Please also validate/allow 453 (common code for greylisting).